# How can I make a dark and scratched metal material?

Tags: materials, shaders, mirror

I am shaping this watch as a training. I did materials for needles and branchs but i'm stuck for the core watch's material.

I'd like to reflect the light like this :

[image: watch]

I use Blender Render for now.
If you can help me, it would be nice ^^

Btw if you have any good tutorial for materials especially those with specular shaders and mirrors. Sry if my english is bad, i'm french :s

Actual rendered view (not full render) :
[image]

Comment: Please show images of what you have tried so far and specify the render engine you are using.

Comment: i only use blender render for now, but i'll try cycles soon so if u can specify for both ;)

Comment: Nodes is your friend here. Look up some tutorials on metal materials, they produce some very realistic results.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=scratches

Comment: Metal is hard to do in Blender Render... I think cycles will make things a lot easier for you